# Consuming parameters received from apex:canvasApp in OAuth 2.0 authentication mode

Tags: integration, oauth2, connected-apps, canvas

I have created connected app that would like to be rendered over Canvas mode.

In Canvas configuration I have selected OAuth 2.0 as an authentication mode. I have created action linked to following APEX code :

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObj__c" showHeader="true" >
  <apex:canvasApp developerName="TestApp" parameters="{test:'param'}"/>
</apex:page>
```

When I press on the link, OAuth finishes it's job properly, what I can not find are parameters that I expect to be send to my/connected app.

Parameters should be sent at the first call (when OAuth is initated) or at the end, when access_token and refresh_tone are sent or in some other moment ? I am expected it as and HTTP parameter.

What I am doing wrong ?